# Suppose that a sequence of independent tosses are made with a coin for which the probability of obtaining a head on each given toss is $1/30$.

Tags: probability

> (a) Let $X$ be the number of flips until the first heads is obtained.
>    What is the distribution of $X$?
>   (b) What is the probability that $X = 5$?

Hello all! 
I answered the second question by finding the probability that the game would end after 1,2,3,4 toss and then subtracting that from 1 to find the probability that it would end on the 5th toss. I'm not sure if this is correct however.

I'm also really not sure how to answer (a) as were only given a finite number of tosses in (b) so I'm not sure how to show the probability distribution for (a) without that information.

Thank you for any & all help.

[image: answertob]

Comment: On a) have a look at [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). On b) it seems you calculated $P(X\geq5)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) You are supposed to notice that the distribution of the number of independent trials until the first head follows a geometric distribution with $p = 1/30$ on $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$.
The chance that $X = k$ is
$$P(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p.$$
b) We are asked for 
$$P(X = 5) = (1-p)^{k-1}p = (29/30)^4(1/30) = 0.02910621.$$

Conceptually, your calculation is incorrect since
$$1-(P(X = 1)+\dotsb+P(X = 4)) = 1-P(X\leq 4)=P(X\geq 5)\neq P(X = 5).$$

Comment: Hello! Thanks so much for your answer. I actually did the formula for (b) first but I didn't really understand what the formula meant so I tried to do it by hand. Is there a longer way to do it by any chance that makes the formula clearer? Also I don't really understand why my way of doing it means that P(X≥5) rather than it being exactly equal to 5 tosses.

Comment: It's exactly what your picture says, except you decided to do some $1-$ thing. That was wrong. I think you almost understood the point. For $X = 5$, it should be the case that there are four "fails" and then a success on the fifth trial. Hence $(1-1/30)^4\times (1/30)$.

Comment: Also, for your second question, what is the _complement of_ $X\leq 4$?

Comment: Hi again! I redid part (b) and I understand why formula wise I was incorrect. I completely misunderstood what the question was asking. I managed to do it by hand but honestly, I still don't get why I can't do 1-P(1+2+3+4)=P(5). I can do P(5) on its own and the answer is correct. Is it because this is an unfair coin? I know the complement of X≤4 is X≥5 *(I think at least) but then how come this method works for other questions? I'm assuming it's because the coin is unfair but I'm not sure...

Comment: I asked you what is the complement of $X\leq 4$

Comment: I was editing my answer :-) so I answered your part of the question

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the fairness of the coin. We have that $P(A) = 1-P(\bar A)$, where $A$ is some event and $\bar A$ is it complement. Here if we call $A = X\geq 5$, then you calculated $1-P(\bar A) = P(A)$. In other words, yes the complement of $X \leq 4$ is $X \geq 5$. So by calculating $1-P(\bar A)$, you really are calculating the chance that $X = 5\cup X=6\cup \dotsb = X\geq 5$.

Comment: Oh, it was implied that the possible values of $X$ are $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\dotsc\}$. Since the complement of $X\leq 4$ is $X\geq 5$, then $1-P(X\leq 4) = P(X\geq 5)$. Notice that if the possible values of $X$ were $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, then $1-P(X\leq 4) = P(X\geq 5) = P(X = 5)$, since the only possible values of the event $X\geq 5$ is just $5$. The other typical case where this method works is when you are asked to calculate the chance that at least one of some event (like $N\geq 1$). In a typical problem, it might be easier to use the complement $N = 0$; hence $P(N\geq 1) = 1-P(N = 0)$.